# What does express - app.get do?

Tags: express, routes

I am doing a tutorial in express and I need help understanding this code:

on the routes/index folder is this code:

```
module.exports = (app) => {
  app.get('/api', (req, res) => res.status(200).send({
    message: 'Welcome to the Todos API!',
  }));

  app.post('/api/todos', todosController.create);
};
```

and in the app file where it's use is this code, which I don't understand:

```
require('./server/routes')(app);
```

It exported a function but Why is the app used as parameter here?

Comment: Was that helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Express.js supports the following routing methods that correspond to HTTP methods: get, post, put, head, delete e.t.c. Therefore we can pass the express instance as a parameter of a function which handles the routing for us. The express instance in most tutorials is created as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
// And then we instantiate express
var app = express();
```

We can then access the express methods in a separate file by providing it as an argument to a function.

```
module.exports = (app) =>
```

Here it could have been given any name, but calling it app makes everything more clearer to the reader. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The app object conventionally denotes the Express application. app.get(path, callback) routes HTTP GET requests to the specified path with the specified callback functions.

If its app.get('name') , where 'name' is one of strings in the app settings, returns the value of name app setting.

There are two use cases for app.get()